# Pasar valores entre archivos JS

Tags: jquery

Tengo dos páginas .aspx con su respectivo archivo .js, he pasado entre ambas información por medio de parámetros en la URL pero desearía pasarle desde un .js al otro una variable que tiene demasiada información... hay alguna forma de pasar otro parámetro sin que sea por medio de URL??

Comment: ¿Qué es para ti "demasiada información? ¿Qué es realmente lo que quieres lograr? ¿Podrías ampliar un poco mas tu problema? Puede ser que sea un error de concepto o de como quieras resolver tu problema.

Comment: Demasiada información es una variable JSON que representa 4 tablas de una base de datos, ya la tengo en variable, pero necesito pasarla al otro js para no volver a consultar la información por medio de AJAX, ya que tarda demasiado la consulta

Comment: Ok, esa información es muy buena y solo te dejo mis pensamientos: 1. quizas podrias atacar el problema desde la perspectiva de la BD, ¿porque tarda tanto? ¿como mejorar el rendimiento de la consulta? o 2. quizas podrias atacar el problema desde la perspectiva de la usabilidad. ¿realmente puede una persona visualizar informacion de 4 tablas en su pantalla? Podrias ir cargandola segun sea necesario y por lo tanto no se tardaria tanto.

Comment: jejeje lo haría, podría optimizar eso, pero yo no tengo control de los resultados de la base de datos, asi que solo me gustaría hacer 1 petición para obtener los datos y de ahi manipularla toda, pero no sé como pasar esa variable al otro JS

Answer (score 2):

Creo que la solución más(*menos*) recomonedable sería usar variables globales de la siguiente forma:

```
// No usar ninguna palabra reservada para crear la variable
data = { //mi información de 10mb }
```

Luego, desde cualquier otro archivo JavaScript puedes acceder a ella de la siguiente forma:

```
window.data // { //mi información de 10mb }
```

Esta es otra solución depende enteramente del orden ejecución de tus archivos `.js`

```
<script src="script1.js"></script> <!-- var X = 10; -->
<script src="script1.js"></script> <!-- console.log(X); // 10 -->
```

También puedes hacer uso de [**localStorage**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) (La capacidad máxima de almacenamiento para Google Chrome es de 10MB)

```js
// Aquí tienes tu variable, objeto, arreglo, lo que sea, definido en el script1.js
var data = {
  "name": "John",
  "lastname": "Doe",
  "age": 22,
  "isLogged": true,
  "pass": 1234567890
};

// Lo parseamos a texto para guardarlo en el localStorage
localStorage.setItem("data", JSON.stringify(data));

// Lo parseamos a un objeto cuando lo queremos traer para
// tratar de nuevo con el archivo script2.js
var dataFromlocalStorage = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("data"));
```

Comment: Gracias, ya tengo la variable en JSON, pero necesito pasarla al otro JS, el problema es que son más de 10mb, ya que mi variable JSON representa 4 tablas de una base de datos obtenida por AJAX

Comment: Entonces, ¿por qué no usar un archivo JSON externo y un pequeño servicio en PHP o en lo que sea que tengas el backend para tratarlo?

Comment: Obtengo el resultado de la base de datos por medio de un servicio, pero no quiero estar usando el mismo servicio cada que quiera información... ya que basta con que lo use una sola vez para tener toda la información que necesito, perooo no sé como psarlo al otro js

Comment: @EriK prueba con la primera solución que te planteé de las variables globales

Answer (score 0):

Tienes varias posibles soluciones:

**1)** Guardar la variable en una cookie, puedes encontrar más información en este enlace [W3School Cookies](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp).

Métodos auxiliares

```
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires="+ d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
}

function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
    var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
    for(var i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
            c = c.substring(1);
        }
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

Guardar variable:

`setCookie("nombreCookie", JSON.stringify(valueCookie), 1);`

Obtener variable:

`var miVariable = JSON.parse(getCookie("nombreCookie"));`

**2)** Guardar la variable en local storage, puedes encontrar más información en este enlace [W3School Local Stoage](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp).

Guardar variable:

`localStorage.setItem("nombreVariable", JSON.stringify(valorVariable));`

Obtener variable:

`var miVariable = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("nombreVariable"));`

Si vas a utilizar localStorage, debes tener cuidado de que el navegador del cliente soporte esta funcionalidad:

```
if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
    // Opción de LocalStorage.
} else {
    // Opción de cookies.
}
```